# Graphics object to image file

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing

I would like to crop and resize my image. Here is my code:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Cropper/tests/castle.jpg");

// Crop and resize the image.
Rectangle destination = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 120);
Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(image);
graphic.DrawImage(image, destination, int.Parse(X1.Value), int.Parse(Y1.Value), int.Parse(Width.Value), int.Parse(Height.Value), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Now I assume that my resulting cropped/resized image is stored in the *graphics* object. The question is - how do I save it to a file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Graphics` object that you get from `Graphics.FromImage` is a drawing surface for the image. So you can simply save the image object when you are done.

```
string fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Cropper/tests/castle.jpg");
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(fileName)
{
    using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        // Crop and resize the image.
        Rectangle destination = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 120);
        graphic.DrawImage(image, destination, int.Parse(X1.Value), int.Parse(Y1.Value), int.Parse(Width.Value), int.Parse(Height.Value), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    image.Save(fileName);
}
```

Beware though that doing this repeatedly on a jpg image may not be a good thing; the image is re-encoded each time and since jpg uses a destructive compression method you will lose some image quality each time. I wouldn't worry about that if this is a once-per-image operation though.

Answer (score 8):

No, the `Graphics` object doesn't contain any image data, it's used to draw on a canvas, which usually is the screen or a `Bitmap` object.

So, you need to create a `Bitmap` object with the correct size to draw on, and create the `Graphics` object for that bitmap. Then you can save it. Remember that object implementing `IDisposable` should be disposed, for example using the `using` clause:

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Cropper/tests/castle.jpg")) {

   // Create bitmap
   using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(200, 120)) {

      // Crop and resize the image.
      Rectangle destination = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 120);
      using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)) {
         graphic.DrawImage(image, destination, int.Parse(X1.Value), int.Parse(Y1.Value), int.Parse(Width.Value), int.Parse(Height.Value), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
      }
      newImage.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Cropper/tests/castle_icon.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not a direct answer to the OP's question, but it is an often-overlooked tool that can allow you to approach things in a different way, should that prove necessary.

It is often said that it's not possible to get at the content of a Graphics object. This is not true at all. With the right approach you can access data on a canvas using  HDC and BitBlt. Here is one way to do it using C#:

```
    enum TernaryRasterOperations : uint
    {
        /// <summary>dest = source</summary>
        SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020,
        /// <summary>dest = source OR dest</summary>
        SRCPAINT = 0x00EE0086,
        /// <summary>dest = source AND dest</summary>
        SRCAND = 0x008800C6,
        /// <summary>dest = source XOR dest</summary>
        SRCINVERT = 0x00660046,
        /// <summary>dest = source AND (NOT dest)</summary>
        SRCERASE = 0x00440328,
        /// <summary>dest = (NOT source)</summary>
        NOTSRCCOPY = 0x00330008,
        /// <summary>dest = (NOT src) AND (NOT dest)</summary>
        NOTSRCERASE = 0x001100A6,
        /// <summary>dest = (source AND pattern)</summary>
        MERGECOPY = 0x00C000CA,
        /// <summary>dest = (NOT source) OR dest</summary>
        MERGEPAINT = 0x00BB0226,
        /// <summary>dest = pattern</summary>
        PATCOPY = 0x00F00021,
        /// <summary>dest = DPSnoo</summary>
        PATPAINT = 0x00FB0A09,
        /// <summary>dest = pattern XOR dest</summary>
        PATINVERT = 0x005A0049,
        /// <summary>dest = (NOT dest)</summary>
        DSTINVERT = 0x00550009,
        /// <summary>dest = BLACK</summary>
        BLACKNESS = 0x00000042,
        /// <summary>dest = WHITE</summary>
        WHITENESS = 0x00FF0062,
        /// <summary>
        /// Capture window as seen on screen.  This includes layered windows 
        /// such as WPF windows with AllowsTransparency="true"
        /// </summary>
        CAPTUREBLT = 0x40000000
    }

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "BitBlt", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool BitBlt([In] IntPtr hdc, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, [In] IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, TernaryRasterOperations dwRop);

    public static Bitmap CopyGraphicsContent(Graphics source, Rectangle rect)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);

        using (Graphics dest = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            IntPtr hdcSource = source.GetHdc();
            IntPtr hdcDest = dest.GetHdc();

            BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height, hdcSource, rect.X, rect.Y, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);

            source.ReleaseHdc(hdcSource);
            dest.ReleaseHdc(hdcDest);
        }

        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer the question? Please explain how this answers the question

Comment: Everybody says that's not possible to copy the Graphics object content. This is not true at all. You can access data on a canvas using is HDC and BitBlt. Here is how to do it using C#.

Comment: This is what I was looking for when my search brought up the OP's question, among many others :)