# How to convert Graphic was drawn to byte[] array in C# (byte[] will also include drawings)

Tags: c#, system.drawing, system.drawing.graphics

I want convert Graphic was drawn to byte[] array. This code will show everybody my ideas.

```
        Graphics newGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);

            // Draw it
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256));
            Pen blackPen = new Pen(randomColor, 2);

            // Create rectangle.               
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(int.Parse(val[2]), int.Parse(val[3]), int.Parse(val[4]), int.Parse(val[5])); //val[x] is 4 point to make Rectangle

            // Draw rectangle.
            newGraphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, rect);
            newGraphics.DrawString(lines[int.Parse(val[0])], new Font("font name", 4), Brushes.Red, rect); //draw string for name of Rectangle
```

As you can see, after perform draw `newGraphics` is an image that has been drawn.

My idea got here, i don't know how to convert it to byte[]
Because i still don't understand System.Drawing.Graphics of C#

Hope everybody help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to convert Graphic was drawn to byte[] array in C# (byte[] will also include drawings)

When you use

```cs
Graphics newGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)
```

what you're basically doing is taking that original `image` and [drawing directly to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147156/graphics-object-to-image-file) using the [`Graphics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=net-5.0) methods.

When you're done drawing with `Graphics` you could [just save the `image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=net-5.0) or [convert the `image` to a byte[].](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array)

Make sure to also `Dispose()` of the `Graphics` when your done as well, since it uses resources like memory and other [`IDisposable][4]` objects that need to be cleaned up before they can be collected by the Garbage Collector

Comment: So when I convert image to byte[] array, it already includes the drawing, right?

Comment: Yup! Any commands you run on the `Graphics` and you finish by using `Graphics`.`DrawImage(image...)` the original `image` should contain the newly drawn stuff

Comment: Checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147156/graphics-object-to-image-file) it has really good examples on how to use the `Graphics` to draw onto an `image` and save it